# Delete Files from Local Server after uploaded to s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have successfully got the local directory with files on the local server uploaded to my test s3 bucket. 
Where im struggling is when the directories are uploaded to s3, i want those same directories on the local server to be deleted. ideally i would like to keep the 10 last added files. "as these my be actively written to from background processes and would like to not disrupt that."

Im not the strongest in python and am having difficulty trying to figure out how i can add the deletion part to my current python script. Any help or suggestions would be helpful.

```
import os, time, sys
import boto3


s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="us-east-2")

def upload_objects():
    try:
        bucket_name = "Testbucket" #s3 bucket name
        root_path = 'C:/Path/Test/' # local folder for upload

        my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)

        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
            path = path.replace("\\","/")
            directory_name = path.replace(root_path,"")
            for file in files:
                my_bucket.upload_file(os.path.join(path, file), directory_name+'/'+file)

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    upload_objects()
```

Comment: You want to delete directory after it has been pushed? I would put it following `for file in files:` loop, but outside of it just before the `except` line

Comment: Correct, after the push to s3 i no longer need those files locally anymore. So on the local server, everthing after /Test/* will be deleted.

Comment: did you tried shutil.rmtree https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree

Comment: i have not, thanks ill give this a go.

Comment: Pay attention that this will delete the whole tree, a mistake can be dangerous